# Позиционирование span блока

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Как запретить тексту съезжать в левый край?
Нужно, чтобы "Выберите город..." был в пределах блока span и находился под "Выберите страну..."

http://jsfiddle.net/4aPe2/5/

```css
.item {
    height: 30px;
}
.item span.tlt {
    min-width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
span.tlt {
    color: gray;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.info {
    width: 390px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
<div class="item"><span class="tlt">Город:</span> <span>Выберите страну..., Выберите город...</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задаем span нужный id, например "text".
Пишем css свойства:

```
#text {
float: right;
width: 170px;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/4aPe2/9/

```css
.item {
    height: 30px;
}
#text {
    float: right;
    width: 170px;
}
.item span.tlt {
    min-width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
span.tlt {
    color: gray;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.info {
    width: 390px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
    <div class="item"><span class="tlt">Город:</span>  <span id="text">Выберите страну..., Выберите город...</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Задать спану с выбором города и страны класс (например tlt1) и изменять ему свойства как нужно.

```
.tlt1 {
    float: right;
}
```

Поставить тег переноса строки (
) после "Выберите страну..."

http://jsfiddle.net/4aPe2/11/

```css
.item {
  height: 30px;
}
.item span.tlt {
  min-width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
span.tlt {
  color: gray;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.tlt1 {
  float: right;
}
.info {
  width: 390px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="item"><span class="tlt">Город:</span>  <span class="tlt1">Выберите страну...,<br />Выберите город...</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.item {
    height: 30px;
}

.tlt {
    min-width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tlt {
    color: gray;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.info {
    width: 390px;
}

.val {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
<div class="item"><span class="tlt">Город:</span> <span class="val">Выберите страну...,<br>Выберите город...</span></div>
</div>
```